# Can Reinforcement Learning be used to generate sequences?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reference-request, applications, sequence-modeling, seq2seq

Can we use reinforcement learning for sequence-to-sequence tasks? If yes, whether or not this is a good choice, how could this be done?

Answer (score 3):

One renowned example for the specified case is [SeqGAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.05473)

> Modeling **the data generator as a stochastic policy in reinforcement learning (RL)**, SeqGAN bypasses the generator differentiation problem by directly performing gradient policy update. **The RL reward signal comes from the GAN discriminator judged on a complete sequence**, and is passed back to the intermediate state-action steps using Monte Carlo search. Extensive experiments on synthetic data and real-world tasks demonstrate significant improvements over strong baselines.